# What is the name of the platform(s) when we develop using PHP?

Tags: java, php, development-environment, platform

> Services written in C# running on .NET platforms and services written
>   in Java running on Java EE platforms, for example, can both be
>   consumed by a common composite application (or client).

This is what I read under Wikipedia trying to understand the concept of services and service-oriented architectures (SOA). It triggered a question for which i still don't find an answer me who developped with PHP for years.

It may sound silly, but it is important for me. What is the name of the platform(s) when we develop using PHP?

Is there a simplified definition of 'platform' somewhere on the web?  A link will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: platform's a buzzword. read it as "tool". whether it's a hammer which does only one thing, or a swiss army knife that does 500, it's still just a tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is an interpreter language, not to be confused with C# or Java. It does not run on a platform, it is just a stack of code that is interpreted by the server and the server respond with the result of your request.

At least from my knowledge :)

EXTRAS FROM WIKIPEDIA:

> PHP development began in 1994 when Rasmus Lerdorf wrote a series of
>   Common Gateway Interface (CGI) binaries in C,[6][11][12][13] which he
>   used to maintain his personal homepage. He extended them to add the
>   ability to work with web forms and to communicate with databases, and
>   called this implementation "Personal Home Page/Forms Interpreter" or
>   PHP/FI.
>
> PHP/FI could be used to build simple, dynamic web applications.
>   Lerdorf initially announced the release of PHP/FI as "Personal Home
>   Page Tools (PHP Tools) version 1.0" publicly to accelerate bug
>   location and improve the code, on the Usenet discussion group
>   comp.infosystems.www.authoring.cgi on June 8, 1995.[14][15] This
>   release already had the basic functionality that PHP has as of 2013.
>   This included Perl-like variables, form handling, and the ability to
>   embed HTML. The syntax resembled that of Perl but was simpler, more
>   limited and less consistent.[6]

read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a scripting language, not compiled but interpreted. It does not require any platform to be run.

Unlike Java or C #, you just get PHP binary, and run your script.

[Wikipedia says :](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform)

> A computing platform is, in the most general sense, whatever pre-existing environment a piece of software is designed to run within, obeying its constraints, and making use of its facilities. Typical platforms include a hardware architecture, an operating system (OS), and runtime libraries

So basically, for PHP, the plateform is just the PHP binary, kind of. If you want to take a step back, it could include the Apache server.

Comment: Thank you this really makes my understanding broader.